# Java ANTLR4 mismatched input '<EOF>' when validating python comment

Tags: python, python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

This is my grammar file, I am trying to parse a comment from starting of any content. my comment is python (#) single line and (""") multiline comment.
I am getting below error during the parsing the below test cases.

test case scenario for sigle line comment

1. `# This is single line comment.\nme = "Test Name"\nt = test(me)\nreturn t` **FAIL**
2. `# This is single line comment.` **PASS**
3. `me = "Test Name"\n# This is single line comment.\nt = test(me)\nreturn t` **PASS**

test case scenario for multi line comment

1. `"""This is comment.\nThis is comment.\n"""\nme = "Test Name"\nt = test(me)\nreturn t` **FAIL**
2. `"""This is comment.\nThis is comment.\n"""` **PASS**
3. `me = "Test Name"\n"""This is comment.\nThis is comment.\n"""\nt = test(me)\nreturn t` **PASS**

antlr4.error.Errors.ParseCancellationException: Line 2: 0 extraneous input 'me' expecting {, NEWLINE}

```
grammar ngc_grammar;

parse
 : (multi_statement | NEWLINE*) EOF
 ;

multi_statement
 : (statement NEWLINE*)+
 ;

statement
 : return_statement
 | conditional_statement
 | function_invocation
 | assignment
 | for_loop
 ;

conditional_statement
 : if_statement (NEWLINE+ elif_statement)* (NEWLINE+ else_statement)?
 ;

if_statement
 : IF SPACE logical_expression ':' NEWLINE SPACE statement
 ;

elif_statement
 : ELIF SPACE logical_expression ':' NEWLINE SPACE statement
 ;

else_statement
 : ELSE ':' NEWLINE SPACE statement
 ;

return_statement
 : RETURN SPACE (expr | logical_expression)
 ;

logical_expression
 : '(' SPACE? logical_expression SPACE? ')'                                                       #BracketedLogicalExpr
 | NOT SPACE logical_expression                                                                   #LogicalNotExpr
 | left=logical_expression SPACE operator=OR SPACE right=logical_expression                       #LogicalExpr
 | left=logical_expression SPACE operator=AND SPACE right=logical_expression                      #LogicalExpr
 | boolean_expression                                                                             #LogicalBooleanExpr
 ;

boolean_expression
 : left=expr SPACE? operator=(GT | GTE | LT | LTE | EQ | NE | IN | NOT_IN | IS | IS_NOT) SPACE? right=expr      #ComparisonExpr
 | expr                                                                                                         #BooleanFunctionExpr
 ;

expr
 : term (SPACE? arith_expr)*
 ;

arith_expr
 : operator=(PLUS|MINUS) SPACE? term
 ;

term
 : factor (SPACE? factor_expr)*
 ;

factor_expr
 : operator=(TIMES|DIV) SPACE? factor
 ;

factor
 : operator=(PLUS|MINUS) SPACE? factor | value
 ;

value
 : atom_expr | function_invocation
 ;

atom_expr
 : atom trailer*                 #AtomExprAtom
 | '(' SPACE? expr SPACE? ')'    #AtomExprBracket
 ;

trailer
 : '(' parameters ')'                                                                               # TrailerFunction
 | '[' string_atom ']'                                                                              # TrailerIndex
 | '.' identifier                                                                                   # TrailerProp
 ;

function_invocation
 : identifier '(' parameters ')'                            # FunctionInvocation
 | atom trailer+                                            # FunctionAccessor
 ;

assignment
 : identifier SPACE? '=' SPACE? expr                            #VariableAssignment
 | variable_accessor '.' identifier SPACE? '=' SPACE? expr      #PropAssignment
 ;

parameters
 : (value SPACE? (',' SPACE? value)*)?
 ;

array
 : '[' SPACE? (value SPACE? (',' SPACE? value)*)? SPACE? ']'
 ;

for_loop
: FOR SPACE var=identifier SPACE* (',' SPACE* index=identifier)? SPACE IN SPACE atom ':' NEWLINE SPACE assignment #forLoop
;

atom
 : none_atom
 | boolean_atom
 | float_atom
 | integer_atom
 | string_atom
 | array
 | variable_accessor
 ;

variable_accessor
 : identifier
 ;

none_atom
 : NONE
 ;

boolean_atom
 : TRUE
 | FALSE
 ;

integer_atom
 : INTEGER
 ;

float_atom
 : FLOAT
 ;

string_atom
 : STRING_LITERAL
 ;

identifier
 : NAME
 ;

FOR: 'for';
AND: 'and';
ELIF: 'elif';
ELSE: 'else';
FALSE: 'False';
FLOAT: ( '0' | [1-9] [0-9]* ) '.' [0-9]+;
IF: 'if';
IN: 'in';
IS: 'is';
IS_NOT: 'is not';
NOT_IN: 'not in';
INTEGER: ( '0' | [1-9] [0-9]* );
NEWLINE: ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' | '\f' );
NONE: 'None';
NOT: 'not';
OR: 'or';
RETURN: 'return';
SPACE: [ \t]+;
STRING_LITERAL
 : '"'.*?'"'
 | '\''.*?'\''
 ;
TRUE: 'True';

GT: '>';
GTE: '>=';
LT: '<';
LTE: '<=';
EQ: '==';
NE: '!=';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
TIMES: '*';
DIV: '/';

NAME: ID_START ID_CONTINUE*;
SINGLELINECOMMENT: '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
MULTILINECOMMENT: ('"""') .*? (MULTILINECOMMENT | '"""') -> skip;

fragment ID_START
 : '_'
 | [A-Z]
 | [a-z]
 ;

fragment ID_CONTINUE
 : ID_START
 | [0-9]
 ;
```

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: for single line comment the input is # This is first line comment and for multiline comment input is '"""This is first line comment.\nThis is second line comment\n"""'

Comment: if I am parsing both single-line-comment and multi-line-comment from starting of any content it's not working but if I am passing inside any content or after adding it to last of content it's working fine.

Comment: You have tags in the question for antlr3 and antlr4, and the title says "ANTLR4". Which is it, antlr3 or antlr4? Or both?

Comment: Triple-quotes create string literals, not comments. Also, it looks like your `MULTILINECOMMENT` rule ends with either `MULTILINECOMMENT` or `"""`, and that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: for single line           # This is the first line comment                                                                   
and for multiline comments, input is           """This is first line comment.\nThis is second line comment\n"""

Comment: Well, I recommend not using Antlr3. It's very old. I can't tell exactly the input here. I assume `# hi there\n`. In that case, the grammar doesn't parse this because you don't allow an empty file, or one with just newlines. Try replacing with `parse : (multi_statement | NEWLINE*) EOF ;`. But, who knows.

Comment: Thanks @kaby76 , I am able to parse it with # hi there\n but I am failing for remaining cases like:-  # This is single line comment.\nme = "Test Name"\nt = test(me)\nreturn t